# iOS - Objective-C unable to dequeue a cell with identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, menu

'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier news  - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

```
#import "SidebarViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"



@interface SidebarViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *menuItems;
@end



@implementation SidebarViewController


    NSArray *menuItems;



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        //custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    menuItems = @[@"title", @"news ", @"comments", @"map", @"calendar", @"wishlist", @"bookmark", @"tag"];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return menuItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Identifier looks like:

[image]

what can i do with this?

i'm trying to add left side slide menu, but it crashes when i push menu button.

Comment: Are they static cells?  If not, why do you have so many,  those cells al look the same except for text and image, which should be set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If they are static cells then you don't dequeue them, they are just there.

Comment: @Paulw11           they are Prototype cells

Comment: Can you show the code where you created the instance of `SideBarViewController` that you are presenting?

Comment: @Paulw11 the code of SideBarViewController is up there full version

Comment: Yes, but how did you create the instance that you are presenting?  From a segue?  Did you just use `alloc/init` - which is my suspicion or did instantiate it from the storyboard. ?

Comment: I'm trying to complete this tutorial

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Comment: @Paulw11 from storyboard

Comment: Why does the first item say "news" too?  You haven't accidentally duplicated the reuse identifier too?

Comment: @Paulw11 i've started from first cell and then noticed that in tutorial was started from second cell so deleted identifier of first cell and copied in second cell's identifier

Answer (score 2):

You are actually very close, and your problem is a source of frustration for many new developers.   There are two different, mutually exclusive (competing?) APIs for dequeueReusableCell and you have accidentally mixed them together.

1.

```
- (__kindofUITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

introduced in iOs2.0.
This method is capable of returning nil, and when it does it is up to you to create the cell.

2.

```
- (__kindofUITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

introduced iOs6.0
This method should not be capable of returning nil.  It requires you to register a UITableViewCell class and identifier for each index path in the table, and then the cells are created 'automagically' for you.  (This coincided with the introduction of UICollectionView and it is how those work)

Solution.
You are using the first approach (which is fine) but you've used the method from the second.
alter your cellForRow... method to something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"someStaticString" ; 
    //btw, it is poor practice to name variables with a capital. Save that for classes/types
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[MYcellClass alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier]; 
    }
    //configure cell
    return cell;
}
```

or...
register your cell class / prototype and identifier combo with the tableView (yes, you can use the same setting for all indices..) and then leave your code as it is.

IMHO this is a very common mistake and something that is not documented terribly well, only guys who've been developing since before iOs6 and the introduction of the second approach see the difference without help.  Best.

Answer (score 0):

All your cells in given example should have the same identifier because they are very similar. Icon+text is the content of your cell. Cell identifier describe common structure of cell. So, you have to create one identifier for all your cells and set icon and title in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

Comment: yes but in this tutorial said that i must give them different identifiers

Comment: It doesn't seem like a particularly good tutorial.  They could have just used static cells, or they should have showed how to use tableviews correctly

Comment: @LukaJashiashvili I suggest you to find any other UITableView tutorial because this one is definitely bad